# php pdo to insert array dynamically into database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been trying solve this for a while. I am new to php. Please help me to solve this.

I have form in which we can add more input fields whose values are added into an array 'array_names'. The php code i used adds values of added input filds into different 'id' in database. But I want add all input field values into single 'id' so than all values comes in single database table row. Please tell me how to do that.
Thanks in advance!

```
//form

<form action="" method="POST">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="PlanTitle"> <span class="FieldInfo"> Plan Title: </span></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="PlanTitle" id="PlanTitle" placeholder="Type here" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="SubTitle"> <span class="FieldInfo"> Plan Sub Title: </span></label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="SubTitle" id="SubTitle" placeholder="Type here" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="SectionContent"> <span class="FieldInfo"> Features List </span></label>
  <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More</button>
  <input type="text" name="items[name][]">
</div>
</div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="inner">Submit</button>
</form>

//script
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields)
        {
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="items[name][]">');
        }
    });

   
});
</script>

//php code

if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
$Id = $_SESSION["id"];
$PlanTitle = $_POST["PlanTitle"];
$SubTitle  = $_POST["SubTitle"];
$items = (isset($_POST['items']) && is_array($_POST['items'])) ? $_POST['items'] : array();
$array_names = $items['name'];
global $ConnectingDB;
foreach ($array_names as $name) {  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO plan(title,subtitle,items);
    $sql .= "VALUES(:planTitle,:SubTitle,:Items);
    $stmt = $ConnectingDB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':planTitle',$PlanTitle);
    $stmt->bindValue(':subTitle',$SubTitle);
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
    $Execute=$stmt->execute(); 
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Could you perhaps give an example of data, what you're getting now as a result and what you want to get as a result?

Comment: _“Please tell me how to do that.”_ - by executing _one single_ INSERT query, instead of _multiple_ in a loop?

Comment: This question is not related to PDO. It's a matter of getting the data from JS to PHP. **Get the data first**, and only then start inserting it into DB

Comment: Without sample data and table structure we can only guess. In general, instead of calling `INSERT` statement in each foreach loop you should construct your query containing all required data and call it once **after** `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Plan Table

Current Output

| **id** | **title** | **subtitle** | **items** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | subtitle1 | item1 |
| 2 | title1 | subtitle1 | item2 |
| 3 | title1 | subtitle1 | item3 |

Expected Output

| **id** | **title** | **subtitle** | **items** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | subtitle1 | item1,item2,itme2 |

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you ever find yourself trying to save an array in a db column, you are probably better off creating a new table for that array, where each element of the array gets its own record, and become friendly with INNER JOIN.  A quick search will turn up numerous tutorials and examples on INNER JOIN, including many on this site.

If you absolutely must save the array into a column of a record, do what those leaving comments suggest.